# вопрос от сказуемого или от существительного?

Tags: союзы

Россия может извлечь политические и экономические выгоды, выстраивая правильные отношения с Китаем как с одной из признанных мировых держав.

Выстраивая (как?) - как с одной из признанных мировых держав.

Можно ли так задать вопрос от сказуемого к обороту с "как"?

Здесь конструкция с "как" выражает обстоятельственные отношения?

Россия может извлечь политические и экономические выгоды, выстраивая правильные отношения с Китаем как одной из признанных мировых держав.

Китаем (каким?) - одной из признанных мировых держав. Здесь конструкция с "как" - приложение?

Правильны ли эти рассуждения?

Здесь изложены мои попытки применить логику Девятовой в ее статье "Знаки препинания при «как» и синонимичных союзах. Вопросы теории и практики" по адресу:
http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200203107

Или в принципе нельзя употреблять предлог "с"?

А если все же с предлогом "с", то будет сравнительный оборот?

Россия может извлечь политические и экономические выгоды, выстраивая правильные отношения с Китаем, как с одной из признанных мировых держав.

Answer (score 3):

Интересно, что любое сложное явление можно описать различными способами, то есть составить его разные модели.Сравнивая эти модели, следует говорить не об их правильности или неправильности, а об их эффективности при решении практических задач.

Мне методика Девятовой не показалась эффективной, она,скорее,запутывает пользователя. Более интересной  мне представляется следующая методика.

Прежде всего, эту тему легко поделить на две части по семантике: А) сравнение и Б) тождество. Затем их пути расходятся: в каждом случае задача обособления решается по-разному.

В приведенном примере мы имеем тождество, а не сравнение: Китай является мировой державой, а не похож на нее.

Второй шаг - это выбор между "в качестве" (не обособляется)  и причинным значением (обособляется).

Здесь явное значение "в качестве, считая, рассматривая": Россия может извлечь политические и экономические выгоды, выстраивая правильные отношения с Китаем как с одной из признанных мировых держав.

Для сравнения:

Как одна из признанных мировых держав, Китай политически и экономически интересен для России (значение причины).

Answer (score 1):

Россия может извлечь политические и экономические выгоды, выстраивая правильные отношения с Китаем как с одной из признанных мировых держав.

С предлогом "с", без запятой.

Если сократить предложение до "*Россия может … с Китаем как с одной из … держав*", то видно, что другие варианты не подходят.